# Эти ботинки в приличном состоянии(,) если что

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая? Мне кажется, что если нельзя считать "если что" придаточным, то оно выступает в качестве эдакого вводного сочетания. Не общепризнанного, а просто похоже по функции на него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*...если нельзя считать "если что" придаточным...*
А почему же так нельзя считать? *Если что* — это разговорная фраза; это и есть придаточное предложение с усекновением до одного слова (остальные предполагаются из контекста):
если что (что-то) произойдет, случится, потребуется, стрясется, возникнет.

Пес: *— Ну ты это...*
Волк: *— Спасибо. Ты заходи, если что.*

*Вы их разводите, а они, если что, вас сожрут* (С. Корнеевский).

Когда фраза стоит в начале предложения, часто используется тире.
Если что — мэр готов. Если что — я рядом! Если что — звони.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая *нужна*, поскольку отделяется *неполное придаточное* предложение, содержащее более чем "одно только союзное слово" (по Розенталю, http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm ):

> *Запятой отделяются также неполные или близкие к неполным придаточные*
>   *предложения... **Не** ставится запятая между главным и следующим за ним*
>   *придаточным предложением... если придаточное предложение состоит из*
>   ***одного только союзного слова.***

Comment: Если устойчивое выражение "если что" заменить здесь на близкое по значению устойчивое выражение "в случае чего", запятая будет ставится по этому же правилу?

Comment: "В случае чего" не является придаточным. Решает форма (наличие союзного слова "если"); "что" может быть заменено чем угодно и трактоваться как сокращение от любого выражения произвольной устойчивсти (что случится, что понадобится и т. п.).

Comment: Да, согласен с Вами.

Comment: Но "что" же здесь не союзное слово, а сокращение от "что-то"!

Comment: Союзное слово здесь "если".

Comment: А-а, ой! Ясно теперь)